# How to cache with redis being on different server

Tags: django, caching, redis

I have an app server which holds the Django app, and another server for caching. I am thinking to use Redis for caching. How do I pass the IP of the Redis server to my Django app?

Comment: Whatever redis package you're using will provide documentation for how to configure the redis server URL - you'll need to provide more information about what package you're using and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `settings.CACHES`.  If you are using [django-redis](https://realpython.com/caching-in-django-with-redis/), you can do the following:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
        },
        "KEY_PREFIX": "example"
    }
}
```